# Chrome on IOS shows "cross" icon to close instead of "done"

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, user-interface, select

I'm getting a strange bug on Chrome iOS.
An opened `<select>` shows a "x" icon to choose/close instead of a "done" or "ok" button.

I've made a test from a w3schools test page.
http://work.stereoweb.fr/test_close.php

The Select in the iframe shows the "done" button, the one outside shows the "x".
Plus the navigation arrows are different in style and position.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens.
The "x" is confusing for most users, and that's what I get on my current.

Comment: I'm also looking for solution still nothing?